# Angular 2: How to change activated route URL with replaceState

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router

I am facing some problem related to activated routing while using with `replaceState`. What I am trying to do is that after submitting the `form` I am replacing the `keyId` and `id` in the route URL with the response I am getting.

Let me explain here. Below is my activated route URL:

```
home/screen/user/detail/keyId/id
```

I have form under this view where I am submitting my form with below method:

```
onSubmit(userItem: UserItem){ 
     this.userService.saveUser(userItem).subscribe(res => {
     let keyId = res.keyId;
     let id = res.id;

     // tried this but doesn't work
     /* this.router.navigate(["home/screen/user/detail/" + keyId + "/" + id], { replaceUrl: true }) */

     // this one working but seems like temporary fix
     this.location.replaceState("home/screen/user/detail/" + keyId + "/" + id);
   })
  }
```

Above code replace the route URL with new `keyId` and `id` but if I refresh the page it gives an error like can't match any routes. But my requirement is once I refresh the page it should load the changed URL.

I tried `router.navigate` instead `replaceState` but it doesn't work as expected. If anyone can help me in this scenario then I'll be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Also works in **Angular 2+** (i.e. **Angular 9**)

Did you try this?

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private location: Location) { }

this.location.replaceState('/your-url/blah/blah');
```

The above has been extracted from the following [example](https://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2019/4/23/How-do-I-change-the-URL-in-an-Angular-Application-without-reloading-the-Route).

Hope this helps someone :)

Thank you

Answer (score -4):

You can use below code to make this work :

```
 this._router.navigate(['YourUrl/UpdatedKeyId/id']);
 window.location.reload();
```